# Click gesturedetector and a covered pop-up window will appear. How can the gesture be transmitted to the pop-up window without raising the gesture?

Tags: flutter

In the OnTap of gesturedetector, use showmodal bottomsheet to pop up a window. At the same position of the button, there is a weight of gesturedetector. How can the gesturedetector in this pop-up window get the click event when the previous gesturedetector is not lifted

Comment: Similar to the voice function of wechat, when you press and hold to speak, a voice window appears, but if you don't press and hold, the window will disappear

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.